# How much type declarations are enough in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm currently getting more into Typescript and really love it so far. Lately I was wondering about "how much" of type declarations is enough.

Let's say we'd like to build up an Array of Objects, that are pretty complex and contain deeper nested properties. For example one Object contains around 50 keys. All Objects have got the same structure.

Is it "enough" to declare that the type is an Array that consists of Objects or should the type of every different key-value pair of one Object be declared?

Type Inference won't work because the Array is not declared and initialized on the same line.

Personally I'd say that the second idea is nonsense because of it's complexity but I'd love to hear how the community handles those cases :-)

I'm excited about your answers.

Comment: StackOverflow may not be the best place for this type of question, as answers are mostly opinionated and we don't have any context to your specific implementation.

Comment: I disagree that this is opinion based. The question is basically: "is `{ [key: string]: any }[]` a good enough type for arrays of objects?" and the answer is pretty clearly "no".

Comment: "*one Object contains around 50 keys*" - either all the object properties have the same type (you're using it as a dictionary / lookup map), then you should be using `Record<string, whatever>`, or you have 50 different object properties, in which case you need to break down the size as no record should have that many members.

Comment: The problem with that @AlexWayne is that typescripts tying is pretty lax. Hence why this is opinion based. You could do that, or you could not. Now you could argue you **should** strongly type stuff but you really don't have to and typescript will be fine about that. so your going to get differing **opinions**

Answer (score 3):

> Is it "enough" to declare that the type is an Array that consists of Objects or should the type of every different key-value pair of one Object be declared?

Typically, no, that is not enough. If those 50 keys are a finite list of keys that have specific and unique meaning, and that other parts of the application require to exist, then should *definitely* declare those keys.

For example:

```
interface MyObject {
    a: number
    b: number
    c: string
    // etc...
}

const myArray: MyObject[] = []
myArray.push({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 'three' })
```

It may be a lot typing to declare 50 properties, but if each once means something specific, it's important to have that documented for the type system so that your application can verified as type safe by the typescript compiler.

Note that this also gives you, the developer, quality of life features like property name auto completion in your editor.

---

However, if your objects are just dictionaries and you don't know their keys ahead of time, then make your type fit that use case:

```
type MyObject = { [key: string]: number }

const myArray: MyObject[] = []
myArray.push({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, whoknowswhatkey: 456 })
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. So basically every property that is used inside the project should be declared. Makes sense. Having the other not used properties type safe is a cherry on top to make everything type safe but is not necessary, right?

Comment: What do you mean "not used properties"? If you have properties that aren't used, then you shouldn't have those properties. If you have something not used anywhere, you should probably remove it entirely. It's touch to generalize about this without an example, though.